# Is is possible to use Spyder to develop with Micropython?

Tags: python, spyder, micropython

Is it possible to use Spyder in conjunction with Micropython?  Currently I use an application called Thonny which provides access (and discovery) of my remote (USB) device using a remote interpreter dialog box.  I'd like to use Spyder in a similar manner.  Spyder has a remote interpreter facility but I an unable to discover my USB device within facility.  I'm using Windows10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any currently available way of interacting with your MicroPython device directly from within Spyder, but of course you can use Spyder to edit your code and transfer it to the micro using [rshell](https://github.com/dhylands/rshell), for example.

In principle it looks like it should be possible to write a [Spyder plugin](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/User-plugins) for MicroPython, if your desktop Python skills are good and you fancy a project.

Depending on what board you're running MicroPython on you might be able to use a [plugin for Pycharm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9777-micropython). There are Pycom plugins for [VSCode](https://docs.pycom.io/gettingstarted/software/vscode/) and [Atom](https://docs.pycom.io/gettingstarted/software/atom/) but I don't know whether those work for any boards other than the Pycom ones.

Comment: Thank you, yes I've used your idea - rshell with the terminal plug-in. Thanks again